# Are Android AppWidgets restricted to particular sizes?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm making an Android AppWidget to sit on the home screen.

The user's home screen space is precious, so I want the widget to be small. The ideal size would be 2x1 cells.

- [Some documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData) suggests you can have any size you like?
- But the [AppWidget graphical design guidelines imply](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#sizes) that only standard sizes are supported: 4x1, 3x3, 2x2.

  - Does that refer to the available PhotoShop templates or is it a limitation of Android itself?
- I'm finding that a 2x1 widget works on my actual device (HTC Wildfire) but expands to 2x2 on the emulator.

  - HTC have their own [special implementation of the home screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Sense), so maybe my widget will only work at 2x1 on HTC devices?

Is there any way to create a 2x1 widget, or should I use a standard size?

My widget was adapted from the [Simple Wiktionary](http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/WordWidget.java) sample.

- [The manifest](http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/Wiktionary/res/xml/widget_word.xml) has `android:minWidth="146dip"` and `android:minHeight="72dip"`.
- There's [a RelativeLayout with](http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/Wiktionary/res/layout/widget_word.xml) `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

I'm just starting with Android, so apologies in advance if this is a silly question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm just starting with Android, so apologies in advance if this is a silly question. :)

It's definitely not a silly question.

> Does that refer to the available PhotoShop templates or is it a limitation of Android
>   itself?

I was under the impression that 2x1 was a legal size, but I have not tried one of that size.

> HTC have their own special implementation of the home screen, so maybe my widget will only
>   work at 2x1 on HTC devices?

Different home screen implementations might interpret the sizing differently, though I would hope that they would be generally consistent.

> Is there any way to create a 2x1 widget, or should I use a standard size?

You could experiment with smaller `android:minHeight` values, to see if there is a new threshold you need to convince the emulator to give you a 2x1 app widget. That being said, you may have more consistent results with a 2x2 app widget.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In fact I think I've been wasting your time! Sorry! I tried the smaller minHeight values and moved the widget around some more, and I realised that actually the widget IS displaying at 2x1 on the emulator - I think I just hadn't realised how **big** the cells look on the emulator. Sorry, sorry, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [appwidget design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) page, valid sizes are,

1. 4x1
2. 3x3
3. 2x2

That being said, I've written 1x1 and 2x1 widgets and have not heard of them not working anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's the same page I linked to in my question? when I wrote "the AppWidget graphical design guidelines imply that only standard sizes are supported: 4x1, 3x3, 2x2"